# Core Data Relationship data not being saved

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

I have two entities. ent1 and ent2 and one to many relationship between them.

```
let ent1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Ent1", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Ent1

ent1.a = "aaa"
ent1.b = "bbb"
ent1.ent2?.info = "info"

do{
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error {
    print("Core Data Error : \(error)")
}
```

The problem is that only ent1 is being populated and ent2 remains empty.

EDIT:

I tried doing like @Amruta mentioned. And now I'm getting duplicates in my ent2.
I would like to have 10 values in ent2, and thousands in ent1. Is that possbile?

Comment: Where do you create the ent2 object?

Comment: Show where ent2 comes from.

Comment: Wait a sec. Do I have to create one? Isn't that supposed to be done automatically?

Comment: Yes you need to create one and add it to your ent1 object.

Comment: Managed object are never created automatically, regardless of what relationships exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to insert the **ent2** in the same way as **ent1**

```
 let ent2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Ent2".....

 ent2.info = "Info"
```

then,

```
 ent1.ent2 = ent2
```

than call the save

Comment: Wouldn't that create duplicates in my ent2?

Comment: before adding a new info entry you can fetch info with a given id. Then attach the ManagedObect returned to the info of the new ent1. This is how you can achieve one to many relationship

Comment: I'm not getting it.